# How to set relationships between objects on Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, relationship

I have a parse object named `Card` and another called `Category`. I have 15 categories and gazillions of cards. I want to attach each card to one of the categories but in Parse when I try to set a relationship it redirects me to a screen where I actually have to create another category, but I just wanna choose from the existing ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple, should just have used the `Pointer` type of relationship.